# binding int values from server side - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

Quick question here. I'm sure it's possilbe, just can't get it to work.
I've got a gridview. In have a gridview. The gridview is bound to a list of my custom class. The class exposes a link to an image as well as the image's height and width. I have a Image Control in the gridview. I've bound the Image Url to the correct property. Now, I'd like to bind the height and width properties as well. But everytime I do that I get the following error:

> Cannot create an object of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit' from
>   its string representation
>   '"<%#Bind("GetImageHeight()")%' for
>   the 'Height' property.

Here is an example of the tag:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgProduct" ImageUrl='<%#Bind("ImageUrl")%>' 
     Height="<%#Bind("GetImageHeight()")%>" Width="<%#Bind("GetImageWidth()")%>">
</asp:Image>
```

So, in short... how to I bind properties which are not string?

Sample of methods GetImageHeight and GetImageWidth:

```
   public Unit GetImageHeight()
    {
        Unit u = new Unit(Convert.ToString(ImageHeight) + "px");
        return u;
    }

    public Unit GetImageWidth()
    {
        Unit u = new Unit(Convert.ToString(ImageWidth) + "px");
        return u;
    }
```

Comment: your bindings seem to be malformed. check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

DOH! I missed it first time around.. Try dropping the quotes from your binding

```
 Height="<%#Bind("GetImageHeight()")%>"
```

should look like

```
 Height="<%#Bind(GetImageHeight())%>"
```

and returning an int should work just fine. no need for all the busywork in the methods.

I could be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your GetImageHeight/Width() methods to return a [Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.unit.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

This works on my end, give it a shot:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgProduct" ImageUrl='test.jpg' 
 Height='<%# GetImageHeight() %>' Width='<%# GetImageWidth() %>' />
```

In the .cs:

```
protected int GetImageHeight()
{
    return 5;
}
protected int GetImageWidth()
{
    return 5;
}
```

Render this:

```
<img id="imgProduct" src="test.jpg" style="height:5px;width:5px;border-width:0px;" />
```

Comment: but than it's not bound to the underlined object. I need to still have it bound, the object is holding that information. not the page... Thank you...